# iTunes home sharing gets disconnected after a while

Tags: itunes, network, home-sharing

I'm using iTunes home sharing between two Windows 7 64bit PCs and one MacBook Air, over a private VPN using Hamachi.

It works great, but after playing the music for about 30 minutes ~ 1 hour, the home sharing is just disconnected and the shared PC does not appear anymore.

I can make it run again by restarting iTunes at the both sides, but it's quite annoying.

Is there anyone who has solution to this problem?

Comment: what happens if you stream from like Spotify? Does it disconnect in the same manner? I think the problem is in the windows things.

Comment: Are you sure then none of the systems go to sleep? Perhaps you have checked this already but this is one of the "classic" symptoms in such situations.